# What is the proper way to avoid rerenders when selecting an array in React Redux?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, reselect

Is there a way to select a derived array from an array in a Redux store without spurious renders?

My Redux store contains an array of objects.

```
state = {items: [{id: 1, keys...}, {id: 2, keys...}, {id: 3, keys...}, ...]}
```

I wrote a selector to return an array of ids.

```
const selectIds = (state: MyStateType) => {
  const {items} = state;
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    result.push(items[I].id);
  }
  return result;
};
```

I then call this selector using react-redux's `useSelector` hook, inside a component to render out a list of components.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const ids = useSelector(selectIds);

  return (
    <>
      {ids.map((id) => (
        <IdComponent id={id} key={id} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

I am finding that `MyComponent` is being rendered every call to dispatch which breaks down performance at a higher number of array elements.

I have passed in an equality function to useSelector like so:

```
import {shallowEqual, useSelector } from "react-redux";

const ids = useSelector(selectIds, (a, b) => {
  if (shallowEqual(a, b)) {
    return true;
  }
  if (a.length !== b.length) {
    return false;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].id !== b[i].id) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
});
```

But dispatch is called enough times that checking equality becomes expensive with a large amount of array elements.

I have tried using the `reselect` library as well.

```
const selectItems = (state: MyStateType) => {
  return state.items;
};

const selectIds = createSelector(
  selectItems,
  (items) => {
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      result.push(items[i].id);
    }
    return result;
  }
);
```

However, every time I modify the properties of one array element in `state.items` via dispatch, this changes the dependency of `selectItems` which causes `selectIds` to recalculate.

What I want is for `selectIds` to only recompute when the ids of `state.items` are modified. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

I think the best you can do here is to combine `reselect` with the use of `shallowEqual`:

```
import { shallowEqual } from "react-redux";

const selectItems = (state: MyStateType) => state.items;

const selectIds = createSelector(
  selectItems,
  (items) => items.map(item => item.id)
);

const MyComponent = () => {
  const ids = useSelector(selectIds, shallowEqual);

  return (
    <>
      {ids.map((id) => (
        <IdComponent id={id} key={id} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

*Notes*

- I'm using Array.map to extract ids: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
- `shallowEqual` can be passed directly to `useSelector`

With the code above:

- The array of ids will be re-created only if `state.items` change.
- The `ids` variable will have a new reference only if the ids changed.

If this solution is not enough (can't afford the `shallowEqual`) you can take a look at https://github.com/dai-shi/react-tracked it uses a more precise system to track which part of the state is used (using Proxies: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

Comment: Thank you. The solution for me didn't end up being react-tracked, but another package published by dai-shi called proxy-memoize. https://github.com/dai-shi/proxy-memoize. It looks like the official redux docs also recommend this package for the specific use case I outlined. https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors#proxy-memoize

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is to memoize the ids array in the selector:

```js
const { createSelector, defaultMemoize } = Reselect;

const selectItems = (state) => {
  return state.items;
};

const selectIds = (() => {
  //memoize the array
  const memArray = defaultMemoize((...ids) => ids);
  return createSelector(selectItems, (items) =>
    memArray(...items.map(({ id }) => id))
  );
})(); //IIFE
//test the code:
const state = {
  items: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }],
};
const result1 = selectIds(state);
const newState = {
  ...state,
  items: state.items.map((item) => ({
    ...item,
    newValue: 88,
  })),
};
const result2 = selectIds(newState);
console.log('are they the same:', result1 === result2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reselect/4.0.0/reselect.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @HMR's answer I found that in `reselect` 4.1+ you can pass an option directly to `createSelector` to shallow compare the result and return the old one if they're the same.

```
import { createSelector } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import { shallowEqual } from "react-redux"

const selectItems = (state) => {
    return state.items
}

const selectItemIds = () =>
    createSelector(selectItems, (items) => items.map(({ id }) => id), {
        memoizeOptions: {
            resultEqualityCheck: shallowEqual,
        },
    })
```

https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#createselectorinputselectors--inputselectors-resultfunc-selectoroptions